# How to decide which path to take? Embedded firmware or software engineering? Or don't decide?

Tags: interviewing, career-development, software-development, career-switch

I have looked far and wide and am confused about the path I am taking from this point forward.

**My background in short:**

- **Bachelor's degree in Computer Engineering**, May 2018 (the combination of electrical engineering and computer science)
- **2 years of experience** of combined internship (6 months), test(1 year+), and now a firmware engineer (5 months) in an IoT telematics company.
- **Writing mainly C, Python code and experience with communication protocols (CAN, UDP, gRPC, etc)**
- I enjoy tech and engineering in general. So it doesn't matter which position I apply for, given my educational background.

**QUESTIONS:**

- [**This post**](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-experience/716202/amz-google-facebook-offer-reject-reject-my-journey-from-failure-to-offer-at-faang) inspired me to seriously prepare for software engineering positions (**scared of being laid off :(** ) but **what about embedded firmware positions?** Because preparing for these interviews are quite different. Software engineering interviews are somewhat predictable for FAANG (behavioral, coding, system design). Embedded firmware interviews require me to prepare for, unique, and mostly open-ended questions,(forking vs multithreading, the process of computer turning on, etc)
- When I apply to positions. How should I decide from this point on; **'Embedded Firmware Engineer' or 'Software Engineer' or both**?
- What other platforms are more suitable for my questions?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

- Instead of downvoting, could you lead me to a place where I am better suited to ask this question? Or how to better ask this question?
- Not sure why is this closed, I specifically reworded my question to comply with [the rules](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change#2695)

Comment: Sorry, questions on what career choice to make are off topic on the Workplace. It's not specifically on topic on any SE site.

Comment: @mxyzplk-SEstopbeingevil I am not asking which career choice to make. I am asking how to decide which to take and following [this recommendation](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change#2695)

Comment: Didn't you ask this question on Software Engineering as well, and were told there that this wasn't appropriate for any site on the network?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I thoroughly looked at the the workplace [reasons to be closed](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change#2695) and made sure I did not break any rules. Seems like one person helped me so far! :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> When I apply to positions. How should I decide from this point on; 'Embedded Firmware Engineer' or 'Software Engineer' or both?

I'm afraid we can't answer which is going to be the "best" option for you - but in terms of how you can decide yourself..

When trying to decide between a specialized and more general track, it really boils down to the same process as when you're evaluating between *any* two potential positions - balance the variables towards what is going to give you the best outcome.

Those with more specialized skill sets (such as "Embedded Firmware Engineers") tend to be rarer - and therefore are often employed at a premium wage. But the rarity cuts both ways - there aren't as many opportunities available as more generalized positions. So depending on the local job market you may be savvy *not* to overspecialize to the point where you couldn't access a more general position if push came to shove.

Going the other way and becoming the proverbial "jack of all trades" maximizes your potential target market - but that tends to come with a trade off of the other halk of the proverb - "master of none", and as such your earning potential is lower.